# How To Send Application Name To Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I implemented Identity Server 4
but i don't know how send my (application-name) To Identity Server 4 for creating my single sign on project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a **ClientName** property on the client object inside the client configuration for IdentityServer. This name is displayed on the consent view after you successfully logged in.

For more details you can read the compete docs [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html)